# Is it possible to configure Outlook to wait 10 minutes before sending an email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'd like to be able to leave something in my outbox for 10 minutes before sending an email, so I can stop it from being sent if I remember something else I need to add to it before it sends.

Is this possible with a setting or a GPO or something?

Comment: Why not just leave it open for ten minutes while you get on with your next task? Same end result.

Comment: Its possible to set a time for sending a mail e.g. 9:30 a.m.. Outlook > new email > Options > "delay transmission"

Comment: I concur with @Tetsujin on this one. Type your email, then once done, press save and close. The email now ends up in your concepts and can be sent from there. If you really want to delay sending emails, you can make outlook go offline, but that will also stop incoming mails.

Comment: See https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/delay-sending-a-message/

Comment: Hi @leeand00! It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to delay the delivery of one email or all emails?

For one email: [Delay the delivery of a message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba#:%7E:text=Delay%20the%20delivery%20of%20a%20message).

For all emails: [Delay the delivery of all messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-026af69f-c287-490a-a72f-6c65793744ba#:%7E:text=Top%20of%20Page-,Delay%20the%20delivery%20of%20all%20messages,-You%20can%20delay).

By delaying the delivery, the emails will be placed in Outbox folder before being sent. At that time, you can do some changes on the emails in Outbox.

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.